# Drawing a vertical histogram c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, console, histogram

I want to compute a vertical histogram in a console from an integer array.
The array gets filled by this sinus-formula and afterwards two for loops should do the magic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) //fill array
    f[i] = (int)(10 * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI / 30 * i) + 15);

//draw histogram:
int maxValue = f.Max(); 
for (int i = 0; i <= maxValue; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < f.Length; j++)
      {
        if (f[j] >= maxValue)
            Console.Write("*");
        else
            Console.Write(" ");
      }
    maxValue--;
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Here is what my code outputs:
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWUhC.png)

But the result should look like this:
[right solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqaio.png)

Its working partially until the 13th line of stars and spaces...

As i can see from my result: It does work, but somehow the outer for loop only wants to run 13 times and then decides to stop, but i dont know why. This is also why i am asking the question.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the fill array part to:

```
f[i] = (int)(10 * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI / 30 * i) + 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `maxValue` in both the horizontal and vertical dimension, which can't be right.

Change exit condition of the outer loop. Instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= maxValue; i++)
```

...write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= f.Length; i++)
```

...to get this:

```
      ****
     ******
    ********
    ********
   **********
  ************
  ************
 **************
 **************
****************
****************
****************
*****************            *
*****************            *
******************          **
*******************        ***
*******************        ***
********************      ****
*********************    *****
******************************
******************************
******************************
******************************
******************************
******************************
******************************
******************************
******************************
******************************
******************************
******************************
```